# How to display a specific value from JSON object. Example i wanted to display the value of Low and then assign to a variable in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the JSON object where i wanted to display on of the values

```
"asset_risks": [
    {
        "Medium": 2
    },
    {
        "High": 11
    },
    {
        "Low": 3
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to do that.

One way is you can make use of javascript **filter**. You can filter out the array based on Low and take the value from the filtered array.

Another way is to make use of **find**. Please check out the code below for reference.

```js
var obj = {
"asset_risks": [
    {
        "Medium": 2
    },
    {
        "High": 11
    },
    {
        "Low": 3
    }
]
}
console.log(obj.asset_risks.find(obj => obj.Low).Low);
console.log(obj.asset_risks.filter(obj => { return obj.Low })[0].Low);
```

Comment: Be careful that it won't work if the value of `Low` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to combine all object inside the `asset_risks` array into a single object and then get its attribute like this:

```js
const data = {
  "asset_risks": [
    {
      "Medium": 2
    },
    {
      "High": 11
    },
    {
      "Low": 3
    }
  ]
};

const combined = Object.fromEntries(data.asset_risks.map(Object.entries).flat());

console.log(combined);
console.log(combined.Low);
```